# integracion Laravel 5.4 File Manager

Tags: php, laravel-5

he estado integrando como dice en esta pagina https://unisharp.github.io/laravel-filemanager/. Lo que no entiendo es que me sale un error:

```
(1/1) InvalidArgumentException
View [auth.login] not found.
```

Lo estoy integrando con TinyMCE que sale esta configuracion:

```
 <textarea id="ddd" class="form-control my-editor" name="ddd">{!! old('content', 'texto') !!}</textarea>

var cmsURL = editor_config.path_absolute + 'laravel-filemanager?field_name=' + field_name;
      if (type == 'image') {
        cmsURL = cmsURL + "&type=Images";
      } else {
        cmsURL = cmsURL + "&type=Files";
      }
```

routes/web.php

```
 Route::get('/', function () {
  return view('home');
 });

 Route::get('/admin', function (){
   return view('administrador/home');
 });

 Route::post('/adminlogin', [
   'uses' => 'AdminController@loginAuth',
   'as' => 'loginadmin'
 ]);

 Route::group(['middleware' => 'admin'], function (){
    Route::get('/admin/home', 'AdminController@index');

    Route::get('/laravel-filemanager', '\Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\controllers\LfmController@show');
    Route::post('/laravel-filemanager/upload', '\Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\controllers\UploadController@upload');
 });

 Route::resource('files', 'FileManagerTestController');

 Auth::routes();
```

app/Http/Controllers/AdminController.php

```
 namespace App\Http\Controllers;

 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

 use App\Member;

 class AdminController extends Controller{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    public function __construct()
    {
      $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
    }

    public function loginAuth (Request $request)
    {
       if (auth()->guard('admin')->attempt(['user' => $request->username, 'password' => $request->password])) {
        $user = auth()->guard('admin')->user();

          $res = (object) [
            'code' => 0,
            'boolean' => true,
            'error' => '',
            'result' => $user
         ];
       }
       else {
         $res = (object) [
            'code' => 0,
            'boolean' => false,
            'error' => 'El usuario o contraseña son incorrectos',
            'result' => ''
         ];
       }

       return response()->json($res);
    }
 }
```

config/lgm.php

```
 return [
   'use_package_routes' => true,
   'middlewares' => ['web', 'auth', 'admin'],
   'url_prefix' => 'laravel-filemanager',
   'base_directory' => 'public',
   'images_folder_name' => 'photos',
   'files_folder_name'  => 'files',
   'shared_folder_name' => 'shares',
   'thumb_folder_name'  => 'thumbs',
   ...
 ]
```

config/auth.php

```
 return [
   'defaults' => [
     'guard' => 'web',
     'passwords' => 'users',
   ],
   'guards' => [
     'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
     ],
     'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
     ],
     'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
     ]
   ],
   'providers' => [
      'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
      ],
      'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Member::class,
      ],
    ],
   ...
 ]
```

app/Member

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Member extends Authenticatable
{
   use Notifiable;


   protected $table = 'member';

   protected $fillabel = ['id', 'user', 'password', 'perfil'];

   protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];
  }
```

app/Http/Middleware/admin.php

```
 namespace App\Http\Middleware;

  use Closure;
  use Illuminate\Http\Request;
  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth

 class admin
 {
   public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = 'admin')
   {
     if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
      return $next($request);
     }
     else{
      return redirect('/admin');
     }
   }
 }//
```

Nose ¿que error estoy cometiendo o que me falta, podrían indicarme?, muchas gracias

Comment: Por el error diria que lo que te esta pidiendo es una ruta _/login_. No se si habilitaste el Auth que viene con Laravel, si es así deberías tener en _routes/web.php_   esto: **Auth::routes()**. Si te sirve, todas esas rutas las encuentras en `Illumintae/Routing/Router.php` en el methodo **Auth()**

Comment: @RafaelM si pero lo que pasa puse un midleward personalizado que es para admin y por eso no me deja y saben como configurarlo para que se autentique eso, actulizare la pregunta que lo cambie en autenticar con auth pero 'middleware admin

Comment: te falta una comilla en config/auth.php en guards' pero imagino que fue error de transcripción en la pregunta ?

Comment: @CamiloVasquez Si solo fue error transcripción de la pregunta

Comment: ¿Tienes en resources/views/auth un archivo que se llama login.blade.php?

Comment: @PedroPrada no tengo ese archivo, pero se inicia sesión con esta ruta `resources/views/adminsitrador/home.blade.php`

Comment: Pero ya que tienes dos sistemas de autentificación, deberías indicar que en el de admin la página de login es adminsitrador/home.blade.php

Comment: @PedroPrada vale, y en que parte se modificaria eso? es donde esta los archivos de file manager?

Comment: ¿Puedes poner la traza del error que te tira el debugbar?

Answer (score 2):

Excluye la ruta a la que deseas acceder de el archivo VerifyCsrfToken.php
protected $except = [
        '/tuRuta'
    ];

El archivo esta en app/Http/Middleware

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por responder,puse estas rutas `protected $except = ['/laravel-filemanager','/laravel-filemanager/upload','files'];`, pero aun me sigue saliendo `View [auth.login] not found`

Comment: Trato de recalcar los errores comunes para verificar lo "dificil" al final;  ¿tienes tu servidor de laravel corriendo?

Comment: por el momento no, lo tengo local, si quiere, lo subo

Answer (score 0):

Tienes dos sistemas de autenticación y ambos redirigen a `/auth/login` en caso que el usuario no esté loginado. El sistema de Admin debería redireccionar a `/admin`.

Cuando un usuario no está autenticado será redirigido a la url `/auth/login` (que es la que devuelve la vista auth.login. Puedes cambiar esta redirección definiendo la propiedad `$loginPath` en el AuthController. (En este caso en AdminController)

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

use App\Member;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;
    //Se define la propiedad $loginPath
    protected $loginPath = '/admin';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
    }

    public function loginAuth(Request $request)
    {
        if (auth()->guard('admin')->attempt(['user' => $request->username, 'password' => $request->password])) {
            $user = auth()->guard('admin')->user();

            $res = (object) [
                'code' => 0,
                'boolean' => true,
                'error' => '',
                'result' => $user
            ];
        } else {
            $res = (object) [
                'code' => 0,
                'boolean' => false,
                'error' => 'El usuario o contraseña son incorrectos',
                'result' => ''
            ];
        }

        return response()->json($res);
    }
}
```

Comment: vale, es que ese error `View [auth.login] not found.`  sale en filemanager. Como esto es personalizado nose si hay manera de cambiar eso por lo archivos de filemanager.

Answer (score 0):

Encontré la solución por el momento. Para el funcionamiento de filemanager en laravel se necesita autenticación `auth`, y para un auth admin que es personalizado que es para utenticacion de otra tabla que no sea usuarios si no administrador que lo puse en la pregunta.

La solución por el momento era cambiar en estos archivos:

config/lgm.php

(quitar el auth que está predeterminado)

```
 return [
   ...
   'middlewares' => ['web', 'admin'],
   ...
 ]
```

vendors/unisharp/laravel-filemanager/src/Handlers/ConfigHandler.php

(Colocar de cual auth esta llamando)

```
namespace Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\Handlers;

class ConfigHandler
{
   public function userField()
   {
      return auth()->guard('admin')->user()->id;
   }
}
```